# what storage is best for SQLCE database in azure app service

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a .net website hosted in *Azure D1 Shared*, App Service Plan. Since there is only *1 GB* storage provided for this plan.

I have *SQLCE 4.0* database of size **1.8 GB**, database will not go beyond **3 GB**. I know there are very limitations of *SQLCE* over *SQL Server*, but i have few clients.

I am very confused about the Storage for my website database. 
Which storage should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLCE is a file based database. It expects to be in the file-system of your app.

For that reason you can't just put it in an azure blob storage.

It is also not a good idea to host your database like this. SQLCE is intended more a development SKU and not to run production workloads.

Your have 3 alternatives.

1) Replace SQLCE with Use [Azure Table storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-overview)
This will allow you to keep the cost low, but you will need to re-write your queries and the data access layer of your app.

2) Use Azure SQL service
This will give you a real scale-able SQL solution, cost is not free, but if there is low volume, you can still keep it relatively affordable.

3) **Not recomended** Scale up to a basic App Service plan
This will give you enough file-system space (10GB) for hosting the SQLCE file.

Comment: i can not change the web site code, because its Security Audit has Done, and certificates are given.  Also there are few clients,  there will not be More than 90 Clients simultaneously and also database will not go Beyond 3 Gb. SQL service is costly as i may use about 2.5 GB.  Can i Store my .sdf file in Azure Storage and give that file path in my web.config for sqlce connection string? basic App Service plan  is too costly for these.

Comment: The file path for your .sdf needs to be on the local file system.